# creating elastic load balancer in VPC

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I read that its possible to create elastic load balancer in VPC but I couln't find how to create it. How could I create elastic load balancer in a VPC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS documentation explains how to [deploy ELB in a VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/UserScenariosForVPC.html).